# How do I resolve this scoping issue?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

So here's my problem.

Under `template="one"`, I grab a list from my DOM that becomes unavailable in the next section for whatever reason. So I save the variable to `Template.two.value`.

Under `template="two"`, the only reference I have to the information I have is the `Template.two.value` I saved earlier. Now since it's an array of objects (each of which has a param called song_title), I want to print it out to a list - like so:

```
{{#with value}}
        {{#each .}}
          {{song_title}}
        {{/each}}   
{{/with}}
```

Which gives me an empty list, indicating that the `value` field is empty.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using the `with` block? You should just be able to do:

```
{{#each value}}
  {{song_title}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: That unfortunately did not work. I resorted to the `with` block after I'd failed to do the same thing with the `each` block.

Comment: @Louis93 Can you post some more code? Your question is a bit vague. Please post the code for your two templates and the helpers.

Comment: Could you clarify the difference for me though? Does the #each block invoke a function, and the #with block check the current state?

Comment: @Lous93 `#with` creates a block with a different scope. `#each` creates a repeated block where each block's scope is defined by an object in an array. Use `#with` if you've got one object, and use `#each` if you have an array. I've never seen a case where you would use them together like you're doing.

Comment: I made you a gist here documenting the issue. Let me know if you require any more info https://gist.github.com/alouis93/7982837

Comment: Hmm, well I see a few issues with that code. You have a `Links` collection, yet you're using jQuery to determine which links are visible, then using a bunch of `findOne`s to build a list of links. Why not just store a `visible` property on each `Link` and use a single Mongo selector to pick the visible links? Or store the list of visible link ids in a `Session` variable? The only jQuery that should be necessary there is the animations, and even those can probably be replaced with CSS transitions. Meteor lets you build very powerful apps with very, very little jQuery.

Comment: In other words, don't use HTML to keep track of data. Keep track of data with pure JavaScript objects and then let that data generate the HTML.

Comment: Those are good suggestions, but I still do not see how I can use any of those as a workaround. So here's a briefer reiteration of the problem: My list in the first template is *draggable*, meaning the order can be changed. I need to be able to access the list in the changed order, meaning that that information can only be grabbed from the DOM. Or is there a better way of doing this?

Is there a JSFiddle type thing I could use for Meteor apps?

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI sortable? You can serialize the list ids using the `toArray` option in the `update` event callback, and save that list in the `Session`.

Comment: That seems like a valid approach. Whose update event are you referring to? The template's?

Comment: No, jQuery UI sortable lets you define callbacks for various events, update seems to be the most relevant: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update and here's how to serialize the ids: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray